# Is it possible to share an image to facebook using a data URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several canvases positioned over each other that merge into one as data URI. Everything works fine and I can get the composite image to show up on the page, but the other funcitonality I require is to create the URI and then share to facebook. I wanted to try to do this without sending to the server and do it all client side.

the code isn't necessary to the problem but if you want to see it

```
<ul class="button-group even-2">
                        <li><span id='merge-canvas' class="button expand">Save Image</span></li>
                        <li><span id='share-facebook' class="button expand facebook" >Share</span></li>
</ul>
```

with the javascript looking like this.

```
// DROPBOX AND FILE READER

function noopHandler(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    var count = files.length;

    // Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
    if (count > 0) {

    }
        handleFiles(files);

}

function handleFiles(files) {
    var file = files[0];

    document.getElementById("droplabel").innerHTML = "Processing " + file.name;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // init the reader event handlers
    reader.onloadend = handleReaderLoadEnd;

    // begin the read operation
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function handleReaderLoadEnd(evt) {

    // basically clears and redraws the face canvas on load of the users image
    document.getElementById("droplabel").innerHTML = "Picture Added Successfully!";
    var $canvas = $('canvas');
    ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    face = new Image();
    face.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(face, 0, 0, 500, (face.height/face.width) * 500);
        }

    face.src = evt.target.result;
    return face;
}

function initializeDropbox() {
    var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox")

    // adds different events for the dropbox and points to the relevant function

    dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", noopHandler, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragexit", noopHandler, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", noopHandler, false);
    dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
}
```

which produces a really really long data URI!
Any ideas to accomplish the share?

Comment: you can use FormData() to turn a blob into a file input, as far as the submit is concerned. if you have a url on facebook to upload to, you should be able to submit that blob to the url just like a real file.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this out and I'll get back!

Comment: Hmm, okay so I got the blob to work and it comes out as an image object, but I don't think can accept the entire image file... I feel like the only option is to upload to server then share the url... The only other workaround I can think of is if there was a way to make it use the data URI as is without breaking.

Comment: does the facebook API you are using want a url or a file from a form submit?

Comment: I think it requires a URL to the file specifically :( I tried to escap e any sensitive characters in the data uri and send it but no luck.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? Or is it proven to be not possible?

Comment: Hey, I think that this way of doing it is not possible. you will have to save the image to your server and then share the link to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can post an image via URL or  multipart/form-data in the source parameter:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/photos

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/me/photos",
    "POST",
    {
        "source": "{image-data}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```